# how to implement beforeDelete() event in cakephp 3 for all models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In cakephp 3 we can define beforDelete event listener in any Model. But how to use this event for all models. I want to detect all cascade records conditions before delete one record in all exists models.

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ArticlesTable extends Table{

    public function initialize(array $config)
     {
        $this->primaryKey('my_id');
     }

    public function beforeDelete(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity,ArrayObject $options)
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

how to use this code for all models. should be this code in appcontroller?

Comment: you can use behaviors , see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html

Comment: @N Nem your response is correct please put this in answer. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually create behavior class and add the functionality there which will be shared by most of the Table objects. I don't know it's better approach or not but here are the steps i follow.

First create behavior class with bake command `bin/cake bake behavior` , this will create properly namespaced class , and add `beforeDelete` method  there.
Include `use ArrayObject; use Cake\Event\Event; use Cake\ORM\Entity;`at the top
if bake command hasn't added already.

```
public function beforeDelete(Event $event, Entity $entity, ArrayObject $options){
    //your code goes here
   // $this->_table is Table object instance behavior is attached to
}
```

Now attach behaviour to your Table classes

```
class ArticlesTable extends Table{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
       $this->addBehavior('YourBehaviorNeme');
    }
}
```

For more info see http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html

Comment: This is the *sub-optimal* solution. *Every* single model has to be touched for this. If you add plugins, especially foreign plugins you don't have control over, you can't inject the behavior without forking the plugin. We have ~500 tables in our app, this would be a silly and unnecessary amount of work to add the behavior to every single model. This is not very easy to maintain either in case a change is needed. Also the behavior also just acts as an event listener to the event. It is much easier and more convenient to listen directly to the event in a custom listener.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty easy by using [the event system](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html). Read *the whole* chapter to understand the events first.

1. [Create an event listener](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners) that listens to this event
2. Do whatever you want in the listeners callback method, add your logic there
3. [Attach the listener](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#dispatching-events) to the global event manager in your bootstrap.php

Comment: thanks for your response. Is this a normal and acceptable method for check "before delete record condition on all model" in cake php  or exist easy way for this goal?

Comment: @omid This is as easy as it gets, as you don't even have to touch the model layer code. If you want to apply the checks on _every_ single model in your app, then this solution is totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that will work for all models is to:

1. Create `class MyTable extends Table`
2. Define `beforeDelete` method in that class
3. Make all other table classes extend `MyTable`